# GWT listbox not getting populated

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I m using gwt 2.6.0. I have a listbox on my page which is popluated using the following code

```
    public void setOHIInfo(ArrayList<OHIInfoTo> result) {
    ohiListBox.setEnabled(true); // ohiListBox is instance of com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox
    for (OHIInfoTo ohiinfo : result) {
        ohiListBox.addItem(ohiinfo.getOhiName(), ohiinfo.getOhiName());
        GWT.log(ohiinfo.getOhiName()); // 5 data items are printed; no spaces
    }
    GWT.log("OHI Count - " + ohiListBox.getItemCount()); // Prints OHI Count - 5
}
```

The 2 GWT.log lines are getting printed when the page loads, but the listbox is blank.
I have searched in the project, there is no other place which is overwriting the listbox. I have also inspected the listbox element in chrome, it is actually not having any

Any other way to find what is going wrong here?

Comment: No problems in this code. Are you looking at the right ListBox? You don't have to enable it, by the way, if you did not disable it before.

Comment: Yes - I know, just added that to ensure it was enabled. I added a click event on it and verified that its the same list box.

Comment: How do you declare this ListBox?

Comment: ListBox ohiListBox; // This line is at class level and then I have instantiated the listbox in the constructor after initWidget call

Comment: Is there a way to attach any event handler to throw an alert if something else overwrites the contents?

Comment: You can simply look at all references of this particular listbox in your code. BTW, it's not static by any chance?

Comment: Its not static. The setOHIInfo() is getting called and I can see the GWT.log messages getting printed. No exceptions are thrown. That is what is puzzling me. I have searched through the project, there are no reference. I also make listbox vaiable private, so nothing would be able to directly access it. 
Still same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved this !!!
The call to setOHIInfo was async. So, this method was getting executed almost in parallel to the constructor and finishing before the listbox was rednered. Somehow, it did not throw null pointer exception. That is still a mystery.

To fix - I ensured that the listbox is rendered first and then the values are set.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question: have you added your listbox to any container loaded in your gwt entrypoint likie in the following sample?

```
public class ListBoxExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Make a new list box, adding a few items to it.
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    lb.addItem("foo");
    lb.addItem("bar");
    lb.addItem("baz");
    lb.addItem("toto");
    lb.addItem("tintin");

    // Make enough room for all five items (setting this value to 1 turns it
    // into a drop-down list).
    lb.setVisibleItemCount(5);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(lb);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I have just tried your code that way:

```
public class OHIInfoTo {

    String name;

    public OHIInfoTo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOhiName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setOhiName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class ListBoxEP implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        List<OHIInfoTo> result = new ArrayList<OHIInfoTo>();
        result.add(new OHIInfoTo("toto"));
        result.add(new OHIInfoTo("hello"));

        ListBox ohiListBox = new ListBox(false);
        ohiListBox.setEnabled(true); // ohiListBox is instance of
                                        // com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox
        for (OHIInfoTo ohiinfo : result) {
            ohiListBox.addItem(ohiinfo.getOhiName(), ohiinfo.getOhiName());
            // GWT.log(ohiinfo.getOhiName()); // 5 data items are printed; no
            // spaces
        }

        ohiListBox.setVisibleItemCount(ohiListBox.getItemCount());

        RootPanel.get("editorAppContainer").add(ohiListBox);
    }
}
```

And it works fine. Are you sure there is not something else that could cause the problem? Is you listBox already populated when you call setVisibleItemCount?

Comment: Yes, it is added to a view which has some other textboxes also. And the listbox itself is visible, but it does not have any option

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at listBox method setVisibleItemCount(int visibleItems), with visibleItems=1 for a drop-down list. It seems you must call this method to init the required space in your listBox, but not sure...

Comment: Added setVisibleItemCount, but it did not help. ohiListBox.setVisibleItemCount(ohiListBox.getItemCount());

Comment: My project does have mvp4g and gin. But this listbox is becoming visible. I think that is where mvp4g and gin finish their job.

Comment: I don't know mvp4g and I don't think the problem is with gin as your listBox is visible aftermodule load and your project seems to compile and execute without injection or binding errors. Be sure your listBox is well populated before you call, as you use mvp pattern it is possible it's not if you do some thing in the view and some others in the presenter.